# Unable to get redux-form formValueSelector working correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I'm having difficulty getting [formValueSelector](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/) from `redux-form` (v8.3) to work. I've tried all variants I can find with the selector inside and outside ```mapStateToProps``.

In this component, I am getting the value for the field 'radius' (number) and reusing it to resize the Leaflet circle on the map.

```
import React, { Fragment, useRef } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { change } from "redux-form";
import { useLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import AdjustIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Adjust';
import MapButton from "./MapButton";
import { Grid, Typography, Popover, Button } from '@material-ui/core'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { RenderTextField, } from 'components/form/FormFields'
import { Field } from 'redux-form'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form'
import { networkStatus } from 'actions/onlineStatus'
import { handleFormAdd } from 'actions/formActions'
import { withSnackbar } from 'notistack'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  legend: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 0.5),
    borderRadius: '4px',
    boxShadow: '0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)'
  },
  list: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  row: {
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    margin: theme.spacing(0, 0, 0.5, 0),
    height: '24px',
    fontSize: '13px'
  }
}))

const formName = 'geopoints'

function Circle(props) {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    radius,
    pristine,
    reset,
    submitting
  } = props

  console.log(radius)

  const onSubmit = formProps => {
    const data = Object.assign(
      {
        author: props._userUID,
        authorName: props._authorName,
        createdAt: new Date().getTime()
      },
      formProps
    )
    props
      .networkStatus()
      .then(() => {
        props.handleFormAdd(
          {
            formName: formName,
            formData: data
          },
          'ONLINE'
        )
      })
      .catch(() => {
        props.handleFormAdd(
          {
            formName: formName,
            formData: data
          },
          'OFFLINE'
        )
      })
  }

  const classes = useStyles()
  const { map } = useLeaflet();

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null)

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const layerRef = useRef(L.featureGroup());

  const handleClick = event => {
    layerRef.current.clearLayers()
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
    dispatch(change(formName, "latitude", map.getCenter().lat));
    dispatch(change(formName, "longitude", map.getCenter().lng));
    L.circle(
      [map.getCenter().lat, map.getCenter().lng],
      radius, // this is where I am trying to use the value for 'radius'
      {
        weight: 1,
        color: "blue",
        fillColor: "blue",
        fillOpacity: 0.2
      }).addTo(layerRef.current);
    layerRef.current.addTo(map);
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    layerRef.current.clearLayers()
    reset()
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl)

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <MapButton
        title={'Add an area circle'}
        onClick={handleClick}
        right
        bottom={148}
      >
        <AdjustIcon
          fontSize="small"
        />
      </MapButton>
      <Popover
        className={classes.legend}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'left'
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center'
        }}
      >
        <Grid
          className={classes.list}
          container
          direction="column"
          justify="flex-start"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="body2" align="center" gutterBottom>
              Add Area Marker
        </Typography>
          </Grid>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Field
              name="radius"
              label="Radius"
              type="number"
              component={RenderTextField}
            />
            Radius: {radius}  // trying to render the value here
            <Field
              name="description"
              label="Description"
              type="text"
              component={RenderTextField}
            />
            <Button variant="container" type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Save</Button>
            <Button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          </form>
        </Grid>
      </Popover>
    </Fragment>
  );
}


const selector = formValueSelector(formName)


const mapStateToProps = ({
  firebase: { auth },
  network: { status },
  state
}) => ({
  _userUID: auth.uid,
  _authorName: auth.displayName,
  _status: status,
  radius: selector(state, 'radius')
})

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { networkStatus, handleFormAdd }
  ),
  reduxForm({
    form: formName,
    destroyOnUnmount: true,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
    enableReinitialize: true
  }),
  firestoreConnect()
)(withSnackbar(Circle))
```

Thanks in advance for any advice or solutions

Comment: mapStateToProps usually takes in state as the first argument. Is your form state not at the root level? I would make sure that redux form is in the proper spot in the state tree. You can check with redux devtools. Otherwise everything else looks like it should work to me.

Comment: @tgreen I inspected with Redux DexTools and the form is at the root level and the 'values' state is changing with the input correctly. Here's a [screenshot](https://img.techpowerup.org/200405/screenshot1.jpg). I tried moving 'state' to the first argument in ```mapStateToProps``` and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: I am not sure without a reproducible demo but I think it should be `const mapStateToProps = ({
  firebase: { auth },
  network: { status },
  radius
}) => ({
  _userUID: auth.uid,
  _authorName: auth.displayName,
  _status: status,
  radius: selector(radius, 'radius')
})`

Comment: What happens when you console.log the state in mapStateToProps? You should be able to see the exact structure of you form state and make sure everything looks as it should.

Comment: Thanks for the comments however I've abandoned this because I've had to move forward. I tried all suggestions with no success. I ended up just using onChange handlers and useState for each field. I'll probably abandon redux-form altogether so I can't see the point in persevering. Thanks